# calculate `[1, x^1, x^2, ..., x^n]` in Haskell

Tags: haskell

How can I write a `powerList` function in Haskell like the following? I would like it to build such a list with `n` multiply operations, where each element is a simple multiple of the previous element, not `n` exponent operations.

Ideally, the implementation is clean, idiomatic Haskell, and reasonably efficient.

```
-- powerList x n -> [1, x, x^2, ..., x^n]
-- For example:
-- powerList 2 0 -> [1]
-- powerList 2 1 -> [1, 2]
-- powerList 2 2 -> [1, 2, 4]
-- powerList 2 3 -> [1, 2, 4, 8]
-- powerList 2 4 -> [1, 2, 4, 8, 16]
powerList :: forall a. Integral a => a -> a -> [a]
powerList _ 0 = [1]
powerList x n = [] -- ???
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For a list where each element is a function of the previous element, you can use [`iterate`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:iterate):

> ```
> iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]
> ```
>
> `iterate f x` returns an infinite list of repeated applications of `f` to `x`:
>
> ```
> iterate f x == [x, f x, f (f x), ...]
> ```

---

```
Prelude> powerList x n = take (n + 1) $ iterate (* x) 1
Prelude> powerList 2 0
[1]
Prelude> powerList 2 4
[1,2,4,8,16]
```

---

If you wanted to not use `iterate` or `take` for practice, I'd start by looking at how `iterate` is implemented:

```
iterate f i = i : iterate f (f i)
```

To do something similar, our recursive function will need an additional parameter `i`. This is a pretty common technique when writing recursive functions.

```
-- powerList x n = [ 1, x, x^2, ..., x^n ]
powerList x n = powerList' n 1
  where
    -- powerList' n i = [ i, i*x, i*x^2, ..., i*x^n ]
    powerList' 0 i = [ i ]
    powerList' n i = i : powerList' (n - 1) (i * x)
```

Answer (score 2):

List comprehensions are often a shorthand for generators. Generators are used in other functions for many purposes. List comprehensions are often succinct enough to include in-line in a function. The following is a list comprehension version of your powerList function. It is simply named p. I'm lazy.
Two values in the result are a Cartesian product of each with each. The constant that is also the first parameter is needed only once. Go figure.

```
Prelude> p i j = [(k ^ n) | k <- [i], n <- [0..j]]
Prelude> p 2 16
[1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048,4096,8192,16384,32768,65536]
```

LOL a glaring fact, the i or k is a constant and a parameter, ready to use.

```
p i j = [(i ^ n) | n <- [0..j] ]
```

What I find most remarkable about Haskell is that functions like above are specifications rather than directives. Many Haskell functions tell the computer what is wanted instead of what to do to get it, that is, it's greatly declarative which is what is most wanted in a language.

**Edit 4/5/2018**
I am so sorry. Your specification to multiply the last value by a factor was not met by my last functions. Your specification is literally recursive. "where each element is a simple multiple of the previous element, not n exponent operations." The following function does exactly that.

```
pow l = l ++ pow [(last l) * 2]
```

But like iterate, is infinite. Use `take x $ pow [1]` to not have it run forever.

Answer (score 1):

Chris's answer is most likely what you're looking for.

If you'd like to do it without the use of iterate, you can use the following code.

Edit : to avoid appending to the tail of the list (which takes linear time), one can use an auxiliary function `powerList'` to first compute the list in reverse then reverse the output of that function to correct the order.

```
powerList' :: Integral a => a -> a -> [a]
powerList' _ 0 = [1]
powerList' x n = do { let l = go x (n - 1)
                    ; [x * (head l)] ++ l
                    }
powerList :: Integral a => a -> a -> [a]
powerList x n = reverse (powerList' x n)
```

Comment: The runtime here is quadratic in `n`; appending to the end of a list is linear, so generally should be avoided.

Comment: Good point, this was a just my first thought about implementing without iterate. I guess the other option is to create the list with the head the largest element and reverse it when done.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. I almost always forget about passing along an additional parameter.